# Where do I get HM02 Fly?

Tags: pokemon-series

If I have a Pidgey, how can it I get the HM02 Fly in Pokemon X and Y. If Pidgey can't learn Fly, I also have a Hawlucha.

Answer (score 0):

It is given to you [in *Coumarine City* by *Professor Sycamore* at the *Seaside Station*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Coumarine_City#Items) as part of the storyline.